# Rails link from database appends to current controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, controller

I have a model, Notification, that has two fields: text and link. In my view for notifications, I have the following:

```
<% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
  <li>
    <%= notification.text %>
    <%= link_to "View", notification.link %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Examples of links include:

"foos/4/bars"

"about"

"foos"

However, when I attempt to follow the link, if I am in the "baz" controller, the result is an attempt at "baz/foos/4/bars", or "baz/about", rather than just "foos/4/bars" or "about".

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to disable the appending of the link to the current controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to get a relative path to your current controller.
Try doing this ->

```
<%= link_to "View", "/" + notification.link %>
```

Comment: This was staring me right in the face and I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kumar Abinash. The path was relative without a prepending "/". Simply changed links in the database to "/..."